# Creating a GeoExt Action from OpenLayers Function

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, wms, geoext, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to create a GeoExt function out of this OpenLayers [function](http://dpaste.de/rLfIX/), which displays the getFeatureInfo.

I was able to create this [GeoExt.Action()](http://dpaste.de/KQt36/) but it does not give me any output. Any idea where am I going wrong? This is the function [addToPopup()](http://dpaste.de/RMLES/).

This is my application, `http://128.196.142.12/geo/test/test_new.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to add `eventListeners` propperty to your `WMSGetFeatureInfo` control. Working code should looks like:

```js
control: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: "http://128.196.142.12:8080/geoserver/opengeo/wms",
    eventListeners: {
        'getfeatureinfo': function(evt) {
            var lonLat = evt.xy;
            addToPopup(lonLat, evt.text);
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did use `eventListeners` but I had forgotten to add the `''` for `getfeatureinfo`